# The comparison statement

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a=30,b=1, c=5, i=10;
    i=b<a<c;
    cout<<i<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Hello
I have question about this code.
when I run the code, I get the result which is 1, but I am not sure the relationship about *i=b<a<c;*
and why I get the result

Thank you.

Comment: [I get 1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fvKaqx)

Comment: What are you expecting ? What do you think this should do ?

Comment: I am sorry, I mistyped.

Comment: `i=b<a<c;` === `i=(b<a)<c;` === `i=(1<30)<5;` === `i=1<5;` === `i=1;` `true` is implicitly converted to `1`, and `false` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

int a=30,b=1, c=5, i=10;
i=b<a<c;

i=b<a<c

is interpreted as:

1. compute (b<a)
2. compare the result to see if it is < c
3. place that result into the variable i

So this is what happens:

1. b<a is evaluated as 1<30, which is true, so the result is 1 .
2. next this 1 result is compared to c, which is evaluated as 1< 5, which is also true, so that result is also 1
3. this final 1 result is set as the value in the variable i.